# Adding code before post title with the_title produces weird results

Tags: functions, hooks, actions

```
add_action ('the_title' , 'test'); 

function test($title) {

    $mycode = '<div>test</div>';

    echo $mycode . $title;

 }
```

I expected this functions.php code to add "test" before the post title.
It does that. But it adds it also all over the place on the page. Not sure what's the logic, it seems it adds appends it to all menu items of the page.

Am I wrong on my usage of the_title? Or might there be theme interference here?

Comment: `the_title` is used for all page titles, post titles, and menu item labels (menu items are technically posts). If you only want it to apply to certain titles, you need to specify which in your code (just posts? just the current page? etc.). Also, `the_title` is a _filter_, not an action. So you should use `add_filter()` and `return` the result, not echo it.

Comment: thanks. And how would you constrain the_title to affect only title of (real) posts. If I filter by just posts, as you said menu item labels will be also considered which is unwanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_title/) filter has two parameters passed to it, `$title` and `$id`. You could use the `$id` to check the current post type and then do stuff based on that.

```
add_action ('the_title' , 'test', 10, 2);
function test($title, $id) {
  return 'post' === get_post_type($id) ? '<div>test</div> ' . $title : $title;
}
```

The problem with this is that the filter is kind of not aware in which context it is called (*naturally WP conditionals provide some context*). So you might get unexpected results and end up with the custom title prefix/suffix showing up everywhere on a single view, e.g. the main menu, main title, related posts, sidebar, footer..., even if you just wanted to make the modification in only one part of your view. This of course depends on your setup, needs and use case.

Comment: Closest as it can get but indeed I get the code in unwanted places. Will have to edit templates anyway.